# SQL selecting date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a date column, in the format mm/dd/yyyy.

So I'm trying to do the following:

```
<?php
    $start = '05/01/2016'; 
    $end = '05/31/2016';
    $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) date from dates WHERE user=:user AND date between '$start' AND '$end'');
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            if($row[0] > 0) {
                echo $row[0];
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I think the problem might be the multiple AND operators.

Comment: what is your problem? Any error? Unexpected rows returned?

Comment: @olibiaz This doesn't work. The page crashes, error.

Comment: @janicehoplin: Put your query in double quotes. Check the date format. Bcoz it's not the default date format of MySQL.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: `$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) date from dates WHERE user=:user AND date between '$start' AND '$end' ");`

Comment: @RonakPatel, I think you answered both of my questions simultaneously as after I switched to double quotes, there are no results so I think the date format is the problem. Also is double quotes the proper way to do it? I have single quotes and haven't had any problems until I had to use single quotes within single quotes.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira It was just an error 500, localhost is not working.

Comment: @janicehoplin: In this query `'$start'` variable is in single quote. So, there shouldn't be single quote within single quote.

Comment: @RonakPatel, right thanks for your help and everyone else's help.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a placeholder for user, which is good, but why you are not using placeholders for start and end date?

I would suggest you to use this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) date from dates WHERE user=:user AND date between :start AND :end');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

anyway the date format should be `YYYY-MM-DD`, but reading your comment it seems that you are using a string to store date using the format `MM/DD/YYYY`.

While this query will return what you are expecting:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) date
from dates
WHERE user=:user AND str_to_date(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') between :start AND :end"
```

With str_to_date you can convert strings to date, and the comparison will succeed as expected, however I would strongly suggest you to store dates using a DATE column, you can always format the date at the application layer.

Comment: I declare the start and end dates. I'm just creating an associative array to count entries per date. The associate array is structured as "Date0: #entry, Date1: #entry, Date2: #entry, etc..." Yeah I saw a post about str_to_date. I'm just wondering in the future if I should avoid using strings for dates and just use a date column.

Comment: @janicehoplin if declared it's fine even without placeholders, but I like placeholders anyway :) yes dates should be stored as dates, you can always use str_to_date but performances will be poor and won't make use of an index if present, you can always apply the format you want at a later time

Comment: That's what I'm told so I will apply that to my next projects, glad I learned this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely with this date format '05/01/2016'. You're using a date in portuguese/brazilian format that is not immediatelly recognized by mysql.

try the '2016-01-05' format and it will probably work

Comment: I think I have to rethink this approach because apparently I should try and use a date type instead. But I've been using strings... I'm wondering if I should just do a manual comparison with string matching or to use dates... ahhh...

Comment: you can bind a date parameter or just concatenate strings if you use the default date format. It's just a matter of converting date format as a string. Remember that if you use dates concatenation in string format you have to validate the dates before concatenating or you may be subject to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by concatenating. If the dates are done back end, I'm alright on sql-injection right? At the moment the dates are just inserted on back end, when ever the query is processed. I don't know what the word concatenate means in this case.

Comment: Concatenation means adding 2 strings. About SQL injection if the dates are just being inserted in the backend you should be safe. Just be careful not to directly pass data from the clients to them. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.